# I overstayed on a visitor's visa, but married can I go to SA?

Tags: visas, legal, namibia

I accidentally over stayed on a visitor's visa in June/July (only one day). I am Namibian. My husband and I married in October this year in Namibia (he is moving to Namibia). I changed my passport etc. My ID number stays the same.

I want to know if I can go to SA now that we are legally married or does the penalty stay?

Comment: Is your husband from SA?

Comment: Please, we need your nationalities (both) and in which country you overstayed and how long was the overstay, Also are you permanently migrating to SA or just for a visit.  thanks. I'll mark this as "unclear" to show that the question is not answerable until it's edited. Thanks again!